# How can I get my IDE to recognize listing labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, texstudio

I'm using the `listings` package to print code snippets. My IDE is TeXstudio 2.8.8. I mention this for the sake of completeness - I assume the behaviour is the same for all IDEs, which is why I wrote a generic title and did not use the [texstudio](/questions/tagged/texstudio)  tag.

TeXstudio suggests labels when I use the `\ref` command, but those that start with `lst:` (read: that are assigned to listings) are ignored. As a consequence I have to rummage through my LaTeX file every time I want to reference a listing to make sure I get the label right.

I suspect this is due to listing labels being assigned in a non-standard way:

```
\chapter{Example chapter}
\label{chap:example-chapter} % standard way of assigning labels
And he not: I pray thee, that the sons of Noah builded Nineveh.

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-listing}] % assignment with the 'label' option
print("Hello world!")
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-listing}]
    print("Hello world!")
  \end{lstlisting}
  See listing~\ref{lst:example-listing}.
\end{document}
```

Is there a different way to assign a label to listings, so that my IDE recognizes and suggests them when I use the `\ref` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is supported. It would require an explicit feature of the program.

I can only offer an ugly workaround; the idea is to have another comment character besides `%`, so everything after `^^A` is ignored as if it were after `%`, but TeXStudio will be fooled into thinking it's a a real label.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\^^A=14 }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:example-listing}]
print("Hello world!")
\end{lstlisting}^^A\label{lst:example-listing}

\ref{lst:example-listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grazie mille egreg! Is `^^A` an arbitrary character?

Comment: @fenceop It stands for ASCII 1, which can't be typed directly. The `doc` package uses it for comments, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a not-so-ugly workaround that I can live with. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listing} % A wrapper to assign labels in the "standard" way
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{caption} % Used for \captionsetup
\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{lstlisting}
    print("Hello world!")
\end{lstlisting}
    \captionsetup{skip=-2pt} % Narrow the space between caption and code
    \caption{Your caption here!}
    \label{lst:example-listing}
\end{listing}

See listing~\ref{lst:example-listing}.

\end{document}
```

My IDE (TeXstudio 2) now also suggests listing labels when inserting refs. The `\captionsetup`is used so that the caption text is approximately at the same position as `lstlisting` would place it.

[cross-referencing](/questions/tagged/cross-referencing)[listings](/questions/tagged/listings)[texstudio](/questions/tagged/texstudio)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add it in a figure environment and then add the label manually:

```
\begin{figure}
  \label{lst:example-listing}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  print("Hello world!")
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue I have with this answer is that `figure` is a floating environment, and I would rather have complete control on the position of my listings.

Comment: @fenceop You can use the [H] option together with the package \usepackage{float} to make a figure non-floating: \begin{figure}[H] ...

Comment: That seems to do the trick, so I'll accept your answer for now. For future reference: I added `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` to my preamble to make figures non-floating by default.

Comment: The label won't refer to anything sensible

Comment: @fenceop Did you try using `\ref{lst:example-listing}`? What number will you get?

Comment: @fenceop maybe you could set the label within the listing using latex commands directly $\label{...}$ if you set the listing package up in a way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{escapechar=\@}


\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  @\label{lst:example-listing}@
  print("Hello world!")
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeXstudio still doesn't suggest the `lst:example-listing` label. Thank you for trying though.